# Python RegEx for Australian Phone Numbers - False negative - 2 matches in the same substring

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract *phone numbers* from a web page using Python & RegEx

**Australian number format**

+61 (international code - shown below as 'i')

02, 03, 07 or 08  (state codes - shown below as 's')

1234-5678 (8 digit local number - shown below as 'x')

**Common variations of format** (in order of commonality):

Format 1: ss xxxx xxxx   (e.g. 02 1234 5678)

Format 2: +ii s xxxx xxxx  (e.g. +61 2 1234 5678) (note the first 's' digit is removed here)

Format 3: (seen rarely) +ii (s)s xxxx-xxxx  (e.g. +61 (0)2 1234 5678

**My RegEx**:

```
re.findall(r'[0][2]\d{8}|[0][3]\d{8}|[0][7]\d{8}|[0][8]\d{8}|[6][1][2]\d{8}|[6][1][3]\d{8}|[6][1][7]\d{8}|[6][1][8]\d{8}|[0][4]\d{8}|[6][1][4]\d{8}|[1][3][0][0]\d{6}|[1][8][0][0]\d{6}', re.sub(r'\W+', '', sample_text))
```

works well on a simple sample_text:

> sample_text =
>   "610212345678ABC##610312345678ABC##610712345678ABC##610812345678ABC##0212345678ABC##0312345678ABC##0712345678ABC##0812345678ABC##61212345678ABC##61312345678ABC##61712345678ABC##61812345678ABC##0412345678ABC##61412345678ABC##130012345678ABC##180012345678ABC##"

Result:

> ['0212345678',  '0312345678',  '0712345678',  '0812345678', 
>   '0212345678',  '0312345678',  '0712345678',  '0812345678', 
>   '61212345678',  '61312345678',  '61712345678',  '61812345678', 
>   '0412345678',  '61412345678',  '1300123456',  '1800123456']

**The Goal**

Using http://www.outware.com.au/contact as an example ...

The 2 actual numbers on the page are:

+61 (0)3 8684 9912  and  +61 (0)2 8064 7043  (both numbers appear twice - once in the main section of the page and once in the footer)

**The Problem**

```
#take HTML markup from body tags
b = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').text

#remove all non-alpha + white space.
b = re.sub(r'\W+', '', b)
```

Result:

> "PORTFOLIOINNOVATIONSERVICESCAREERSINSIGHTSNEWSABOUTCONTACTCONTACTOUTWAREMelbourneLe......AFRFast100Nov92017EXPLOREOUTWAREPortfolioInnovationWorkingatOutwareAboutSitemapCONNECTMELBOURNELevel3469LaTrobeStMelbourneVIC3000610386849912SYDNEYLevel41SmailStUltimoNSW2007610280647043"

Now if I apply my regex to this string

```
re.findall(r'[0][2]\d{8}|[0][3]\d{8}|[0][7]\d{8}|[0][8]\d{8}|[6][1][2]\d{8}|[6][1][3]\d{8}|[6][1][7]\d{8}|[6][1][8]\d{8}|[0][4]\d{8}|[6][1][4]\d{8}|[1][3][0][0]\d{6}|[1][8][0][0]\d{6}', re.sub(r'\W+', '', b))
```

Result:

[u'0386849912', u'0761028064', u'0386849912', u'0761028064']

I am getting a false positive because I have concatenated a postcode "NSW2007" onto the start of the phone number.

I presume because the regex has parsed the first part of "NSW2007610280647043" matching "0761028064" it doesn't then match "0280647043" which is also part of the same substring

I actually don't mind the false positive (i.e. getting "0761028064") but I do need to solve the false negative (i.e. not getting "0280647043")

I know there's some RegEx gurus here who can help on this. :-)

Please help!!

Comment: What's with all the square brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't search/replace any text prior to using the regex. That will make your input unusable. Try this:

`(?:(?:\+?61 )?(?:0|\(0\))?)?[2378] \d{4}[ -]?\d{4}`

https://regex101.com/r/1Q4HuD/3

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you.

Comment: For future readers I modified slightly to cover a few more variations of Australian landline numbers. Here you go ...  (\+?61 ?)?((?:0|\(0\))?[2378])? ?\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}

Comment: Ah, so some numbers don't include the state code, sometimes the country code doesn't have a `+` sign, and sometimes there's no space or hyphen in between the main two sets of numbers? I'm assuming that if the state code is omitted, then the country code can't be present either. Just let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: Update to regex with non-capturing groups added so you only get the full number back .....   ((?:\+?61 ?)?(?:(?:0|\(0\))?[2378])? ?(?:\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}))

Comment: CAustin, yes. Once you solved it for me, I played with it and further developed a set of possible phone number formats. The above is pretty complete now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Updated the pattern. There should never be a need to wrap the entire pattern in a capturing group. If you want to return the full match, just use `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you use a negative look ahead to check to see make sure the following character is not a number. For example: `(?!\d)`.

This could create a problem though if some data following a phone number starts with a number.

The look behind looks like this when implemented in your regex:

```
(02\d{8}|03\d{8}|07\d{8}|08\d{8}|612\d{8}|613\d{8}|617\d{8}|618\d{8}|04\d{8}|614\d{8}|1300\d{6}|1800\d{6})(?!\d)
```

(I removed the square brackets as you do not need them when trying to match a single character)

Comment: The problem of a number following the phone number is self-inflicted by pulling out all other characters.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer should be a comment, it isn't because of my low reputation!**

I've seen you're updating the regex and I think this variation can help you. It should match very uncommon formats!

```
(\+61 )?(?:0|\(0\))?[2378] (?:[\s-]*\d){8}
```